# Python how to take screenshot of div

Tags: python

i'm trying to take a screenshot of product detail of Amazon item. I found that div id = aplus is the product detail description which is i'm looking for.
So i create code using python and selenium to take the full screen shot of the div section.
However, the result is cropped and only shows partial top of div.

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    URL = "https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Figuarts-Dragon-Saiyan-Approx-Painted/dp/B08S7KVHMP/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3O3TF6V9FJHS5&currency=JPY&keywords=b08s7kvhmp&qid=1668143838&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjAwIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=%2Caps%2C140&sr=8-1"
    driver.get(URL)
 
    time.sleep(5)
    S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll' +X)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.set_window_size(S('Width'), S('Height'))
    image = driver.find_element('id','aplus')
    image.screenshot('yes.png')
```

and if i put

```
options=options
```

inside webdriver.Chrome(), depending on product it takes full screenshot of the div, but it does not contain any image.
I have no idea how to take full screenshot of the div :S

Answer (score 1):

This example you need import the library PIL.

> pip install Pillow

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

URL = "https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Figuarts-Dragon-Saiyan-Approx-Painted/dp/B08S7KVHMP/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3O3TF6V9FJHS5&currency=JPY&keywords=b08s7kvhmp&qid=1668143838&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjAwIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=%2Caps%2C140&sr=8-1"
driver.get(URL)

# now that we have the preliminary stuff out of the way time to get that image :D
element = options.find_element_by_id('aplus') # find part of the page you want image of
location = element.location
size = element.size
png = options.get_screenshot_as_png() # saves screenshot of entire page
options.quit()

im = Image.open(BytesIO(png)) # uses PIL library to open image in memory

left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']

im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
im.save('screenshot.png') # saves new cropped image
```

Comment: thanks alot for the comment!
since i got attribute error for options.~~ so i changed options to driver and it's kinda working. the screenshot was formed but it has empty image. So i tried removing im.crop part to test, and found it only capture the screen, not the particular div searched by find_element_by_id('hlogo')

Comment: @maz32 sorry, it's my error i forgot change this attr i edited my answer. find_element_by_id('hlogo') #it's a example, you need change your id find_element_by_id('aplus')